# Adding Additional Data to be considered in Google Map Routing

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I would like to supply additional data to be considered in routing with Google Map API. In routing algorithms nodes represent placemarks and the edges represent cost between two places(considering distance, traffic etc.). I would like to add an additional parameter to this cost calculation. Do you know if it is possible to do so with Google Maps API or any other reliable map&routing API?

Comment: With Google Directions Advanced API you can take in consideration all that criteria and more in order to create routes. Additional custom weights i'm not so sure

Comment: Give examples of what you already try. With language do you use?